# HTML5 canvas: Text in perspective

Tags: javascript, html, text, canvas, perspective

I'm trying to create my first game to HTML5. And I search for hours like leaving a text persperctiva (for canvas).

See attached what I need. Are two "points" in text that needs to be modified to the effect that I need.
Image: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BVbuU1PCUAA7d8a.png

PS: I managed to leave with only the text "rotation" (basic) and that is not right for my purpose.

**All topics that I found say in response is not possible.**

Comment: "All topics that I found say in response is not possible." **Anything** is possible :)

Comment: @Cristy Adidas is that you?

Comment: I'd rather say : it is not possible with a Context2d with decent performance. Which matters only if the text is animated. If it is animated webGL is a solution, but with a limited browser support (http://caniuse.com/webgl)

Comment: @GameAlchemist As I said in another answer. In this case it would be better to create images with the numbers already "fallen" and make a script to display them? (Create 10 images with numbers 0-9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Canvas's 2d context can't do the non-parallel transforming that is shown in your link.**

To do perspective-like warping, you will need to use the canvas 3d context (webGL).

Alternatively, here is a post on how to interpolate pixels from an original triangle into a distorted triangle:

http://codeslashslashcomment.com/2012/12/12/dynamic-image-distortion-html5-canvas/

This will allow you to "manually" do perspective distortions in 2d context.

Comment: This example set only works with images? Need to do this with text... Lack just that, I think it would be less costly to create all the numbers as image already "formatted" instead of 3D. What is your opinion?

Comment: In canvas shapes, text and images are all the same...just pixels on the canvas.  If you want to perspective-distort only the text and not the image you can use a second offscreen canvas to distort the text pixels and then draw those perspective-text-pixels to your main canvas.  Here's how to merge the secondary canvas:   mainContext.drawImage(secondaryCanvas,x,y);  You mention an "already formatted numbers as image".  If that means distorting the numbers in an image editor like photoshop & drawing those images on the canvas, then my opinion is do it--much easier and maybe better quality too!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there's much perspective involved, so you might get away with a simple skew:

```
var angle = -0.2;
context.setTransform(1, 0, angle, 1, 0, 0);
context.drawImage(img, 100, 0, 350, 100);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fTQcn/

Comment: This example is also only for image. Making rotation is still a bit different than seek (I need to get the idea of the text on a wooden table). Using EaselJS: new createjs.Text ("Hello", "36px Arial", "# 777"); text.rotation = 3;